# Mage::getUrl returns admin url instead of frontend url

Tags: magento-1.7, helper, geturl, router

I have create an extension which used frontend as well as admin end.
**My config code is below.**

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <testimonial>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magentohelper_Testimonial</module>
                <frontName>testimonial</frontName>
            </args>
        </testimonial>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <testimonial>
                <file>testimonial.xml</file>
            </testimonial>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <testimonial>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magentohelper_Testimonial</module>
                <frontName>testimonial_admin</frontName>
            </args>
        </testimonial>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

When i Call

```
Mage::getUrl('testimonial/index/check/');
```

from my phtml file, It Returns the admin url which is `testimonial_admin/index/check/`
From the magento wiki i got the instruction to create extension, which says this
[image: magento wiki module creation]
I guess the router is matching the admin Url first.
How can i get the url of my frontend using `Mage::getUrl` function.?

Comment: the magento wiki clearly says `<frontName>[module]</frontName>` while you are adding `_admin` also, so you have to add the `_admin` under routers tag as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that both the admin router and the frontend routers have the same node. Even if they have different `frontNames`. If you update your admin xml to the following:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <testimonial_admin>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magentohelper_Testimonial</module>
                <frontName>testimonial_admin</frontName>
            </args>
        </testimonial_admin>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

And then when you call `Mage::getUrl('testimonial/index/check/');` you will get the frontend url and `Mage::getUrl('testimonial_admin/index/check/');` will give you the admin urls.

Comment: :: Thanks for the solution. It worked. But from the magento wiki, it says only the [module] shouldn't it be [module]_admin ?? correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: yeah sure, I think it really does not matter as long as it is unique.

Comment: :: One last thing. so a module must have unique frontend router name and frontname as well as unique admin router name and frontname ?

Comment: yes, the xml gets merged together so that you need unique names here :) though I am a bit confused why you need them unique between frontend and admin.

Comment: @DavidManners , isn't this a bug, when a call is made from frontend, it should look in the frontend router, why is it returning of admin

Comment: @MTM It seems to be by design; not a bug. Check out `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::getRouterByRoute()` and you'll see it selects admin routers first, then standard, then custom.

Comment: Don't forget to adjust `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/your_module.xml`
this part
`<testimonial_admin_adminhtml_controller_action>`
that's what confused me